# prove the mean of begin and end value in a liner function equals its midpoint value

Tags: functions

Assume a linear function $f(x) = ax + b$, with $a,b >0$ and $x \in [0, T]$. Is there any way to prove the following?
$$f(\frac{T}{2}) = \frac{f(0) + f(T)}{2}$$

For example:
$f(x) = 2x + 3$, $x \in [0, 4]$, so

$f(0) = 3$,

$f(4) = 2 \times 4 + 3 = 11$,

$f(2) = 2 \times 2 + 3 = 7$

$\frac{f(0)+f(4)}{2} = \frac{14}{2} = 7 = f(2)$

Comment: Hello and welcome to MSE! Would you mind explaining how you would approach this problem? Work you have already done in trying to prove your inequality? Perhaps some context as to why you and/or we may find this interesting?

Comment: @heepo It seems like this inequality is not true. I edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it's not true. The mean of the $f(0)$ and $f(T)$ is exactly equal to $f\left(\frac{T}{2}\right)$.

You can show this by plugging in the values in the equation $f(x)=ax+b$.

Comment: Could you provide the equation then?

Comment: The equation is just $f(x)=ax+b$. Treat $a$ and $b$ as unknown constants. So for instance, then $f(0)=a\cdot 0+b=b$ and $f(T) = a\cdot T + b$. Now compute the arithmetic mean of these numbers, and compare it to $f(T/2)$.

Comment: I tried that before posting and missed something. just did it again. you're right.